# Selector based on text between tags, in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I need to retrieve data from the DOM, but the containers have no a specific `class` or `id`, 
and sometimes they are not all available.

So I could find this:

```
<h2>name</h2>
<p>john</p>
<h2>address</h2>
<p>street 1</p>
<h3>email</h3>
<p>jong@site.com</p>
```

or this:

```
<h2>name</h2>
<p>john</p>
<h3>email</h3>
<p>jong@site.com</p>
```

As you can see, to fetch the email I can't select by `class` or `id`, nor by n(th) element, because it could be the 2nd or 3th `<p>`

The only solution I see is to get the first `<p>` just after `<h3>email</h3>`, but I have no idea how to filter by `text()` data.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the ( really quick ) replies, didn't know I had so many options in this case. I'm going to need this selector in many contexts, so the custom selector will be the most useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always create your own selector that matches on exact text content.

This one does that, but trims any whitespace first.

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    textIs: function(elem, i, attr) {
        return ( $.trim( $.text([elem]) ) === attr[3] );
    }
});
```

Then you would use it like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aXvm3/

```
$('h3:textIs(email)').next()
```

Comment: Why trim? :) Wouldn't it be more usable for `:textIs( email )` cases?

Comment: @Nick - Could go either way. You have a line break inside the tag, and suddenly it doesn't work. I'd guess it would be less frequent that a user would want to match a leading and trailing white space in addition to the text.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)...or an exact match with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) then do [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the `<p>` sibling that follows, like this:

```
$("h3:contains('email')").next().doSomething();
```

Or with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for an *exact* match (where `:contains()` is a substring match), like this:

```
$("h3").filter(function() { return $.text([this]) == "email"; }).next()
```

[You can test both here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mRx9p/).

Answer (score 3):

To get the email, for example, you could do this:

```
var emailAddress = $('h3:contains(email)').next('p').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourP = $('h3:contains("email")').next()
```